# Cannot run program "\ndk-build.cmd": Launching failed

Tags: java, android, c++, eclipse, android-ndk

I have never worked on ndk . But I have got a project in which ndk is used.

it's giving me `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found:`

I tried to search on Google. I got many link 
But all are related to `jni.cpp` file 
But my error is in java file. So i am not able to find how to correct it.

```
"java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: il.co.telavivapp2u.onceapponatime.SharedResources.ocvBitmapPreMultAlpha:(Landroi‌​‌​d/graphics/Bitmap;Landroid/graphics/Bitmap;)
```

I integrated NDK following [this link](http://anjumshrimali.in/blog/wordpress/). 
This project is done by another developer
We are adding some more features in it.
This part is done by previous dev.

I just added Google Search API Activity And Gallery image Activity which will show images on grid. previous dev has put some number of images in drawable folder and showing it into gallery view. it's running perfectly whatever he done at his end. even now also. But what I have added in that the same thing is not happening

After clicking an image on app drawable gallery view , it'll go to a camera activity which will capture image with the selected image as a background. and then we can make edit and save that image. But in case of mobile gallery and Google search images after capturing the app goes ANR.

I have set NDK path and variable to eclipse also I installed c c++ plugins

Also console is showing

```
Cannot run program "\ndk-build.cmd": Launching failed .
```

I am not able to understand where I am making mistake. Please help me.

[JNI FILE](http://pastie.org/8374467)

The ANR happens at line number 207.

**Here is my code:**

```
package il.co.telavivapp2u.onceapponatime;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;

public class SharedResources {
    public static Bitmap bmpOld = null;
    public static Bitmap bmpOldScaled = null;
    public static Bitmap bmpNew = null;
    public static Bitmap bmpNewScaled = null;

    public static int scaledX = 0, scaledY = 0;
    public static int dispX = 0, dispY = 0;
    public static int fullX = 0, fullY = 0;
    public static int picX = 0, picY = 0;

    public static String fileDir = "/OnceAppOnATime/";
    public static String fileTempDir = fileDir + "/.temp/";
    public static String fileTempNew = fileTempDir + "/temp-new.jpg";
    public static String fileTempOld = fileTempDir + "/temp-old.jpg";
    public static String fileTempMask = fileTempDir + "/temp-mask.jpg";
    public static String fileTempBlend = fileTempDir + "/temp-blend.jpg";
    public static String fileTempRetouch = fileTempDir + "/temp-retouch.jpg";
    //public static String fileLastBlend = "";

    public static BitmapFactory.Options op = new BitmapFactory.Options();

    public static Locale localeHebrew = null;

    public static int taskID = -1;

    public static boolean Init(Activity activity) { return Init(activity, false); }
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static boolean Init(Activity activity, boolean force) {
        if (dispX > 0 && dispY > 0) { // Don't re-init to avoid wrong file names
            if (!force)
                return false; 
        } else {
            fileDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + fileDir;
            fileTempDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + fileTempDir;
            fileTempNew = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + fileTempNew;
            fileTempOld = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + fileTempOld;
            fileTempMask = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + fileTempMask;
            fileTempBlend = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + fileTempBlend;
            fileTempRetouch = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + fileTempRetouch;
        }

        taskID = activity.getTaskId();

        // Find Hebrew locale, if available
        Locale availableLocales[] = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
        for (int i = 0; i < availableLocales.length; ++i) {
            String lang = availableLocales[i].getLanguage();
            if (lang.equals("he") || lang.equals("iw")) {
                localeHebrew = availableLocales[i];
                break;
            }
        }

        op.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        //op.inScaled = false; // Not needed if loading bitmaps from drawable-nodpi
        op.inMutable = true;

        Display display = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
            dispX = display.getWidth();
            dispY = display.getHeight();
        } else {
            Point dispSize = new Point();
            display.getSize(dispSize);
            dispX = dispSize.x;
            dispY = dispSize.y;
        }
        Log.w("Display Size", dispX + "x" + dispY);
        //scaledX = dispX / 2; scaledY = dispY / 2;
        scaledX = dispX; scaledY = dispY;

        return true;
    }

    public static void setLocale(Activity activity, Locale locale) {
        // This doesn't work reliably
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        activity.getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
            activity.getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }

    public static boolean haveScaling() {
        return (dispX != scaledX || dispY != scaledY);
    }

    public static void SaveTempBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, String filename) {
        try {
            new File(fileTempDir).mkdirs();
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 98, out);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void RecycleOldBitmaps(boolean full, boolean scaled) {
        if (full && bmpOld != null) {
            bmpOld.recycle();
            bmpOld = null;
        }
        if (scaled && bmpOldScaled != null) {
            bmpOldScaled.recycle();
            bmpOldScaled = null;
        }
    }
    public static void RecycleNewBitmaps(boolean full, boolean scaled) {
        if (full && bmpNew != null) {
            bmpNew.recycle();
            bmpNew = null;
        }
        if (scaled && bmpNewScaled != null) {
            bmpNewScaled.recycle();
            bmpNewScaled = null;
        }
    }

    //                                             0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16
    public static int sample2sample[] = new int[] {1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 16,
        16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32};
    public static Bitmap LoadScaledBitmap(Context ctx, int resId, float fracX, float fracY) {
        // See: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html
        BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opts.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ctx.getResources(), resId, opts);
        int imageHeight = opts.outHeight;
        int imageWidth = opts.outWidth;

        float requestX = dispX * fracX, requestY = dispY * fracY;
        opts.inSampleSize = (int)(Math.min(imageWidth / requestX, imageHeight / requestY));
        if (opts.inSampleSize < 0 || opts.inSampleSize > 32) // Sometimes index=2147483647 for some reason...
            opts.inSampleSize = 1;
        opts.inSampleSize = sample2sample[opts.inSampleSize];
        Log.w("Bitmap Decoder", "Samples: " + opts.inSampleSize);

        opts.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        //opts.inScaled = false; // Not needed if loading bitmaps from drawable-nodpi
        opts.inMutable = true;
        opts.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ctx.getResources(), resId, opts);
    }
    public static Bitmap LoadScaledBitmap(String filename, float fracX, float fracY) {
        // See: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html
        BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opts.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename, opts);
        int imageHeight = opts.outHeight;
        int imageWidth = opts.outWidth;

        float requestX = dispX * fracX, requestY = dispY * fracY;
        opts.inSampleSize = (int)(Math.min(imageWidth / requestX, imageHeight / requestY));
        if (opts.inSampleSize < 0 || opts.inSampleSize > 32) // Sometimes index=2147483647 for some reason...
            opts.inSampleSize = 1;
        opts.inSampleSize = sample2sample[opts.inSampleSize];
        Log.w("Bitmap Decoder", "Samples: " + opts.inSampleSize);

        opts.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        //opts.inScaled = false; // Not needed if loading bitmaps from drawable-nodpi
        opts.inMutable = true;
        opts.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename, opts);
    }

    public static String FileNameNow() {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
        return fileDir + sdf.format(new Date()) + ".jpg";
    }

    public static native void ocvBitmapPyramidalBlend(String fNew, String fOld, String fMask, String fBlend, int levels);
    public static String ocvBitmapPyramidalBlendTimed(int levels) {
        String fBlend = fileTempBlend;//FileNameNow();

        long t = System.nanoTime();
        ocvBitmapPyramidalBlend(fileTempNew, fileTempOld, fileTempMask, fBlend, levels);
        long dt = (System.nanoTime() - t) / 1000; // Microseconds
        Log.w("OpenCV", "Blended (pyramidal) bitmaps in " + (dt / 1000.0f) + " ms");

        //fileLastBlend = fBlend;
        return fBlend;
    }

    public static native void ocvBitmapPreMultAlpha(Bitmap bitmapImg, Bitmap bitmapMask);
    public static void ocvBitmapPreMultAlphaTimed(Bitmap bitmapImg, Bitmap bitmapMask) {
        long t = System.nanoTime();
        ocvBitmapPreMultAlpha(bitmapImg, bitmapMask);
        long dt = (System.nanoTime() - t) / 1000; // Microseconds
        Log.i("Native", "Applied premultiplied alpha to bitmap in " + (dt / 1000.0f) + " ms");
    }

    public static native void ocvBitmapContrastSaturationSet(Bitmap bitmapImg);
    public static void ocvBitmapContrastSaturationSetTimed(Bitmap bitmapImg) {
        long t = System.nanoTime();
        ocvBitmapContrastSaturationSet(bitmapImg);
        long dt = (System.nanoTime() - t) / 1000; // Microseconds
        Log.i("Native", "Assigned contrast/saturation bitmap in " + (dt / 1000.0f) + " ms");
    }

    public static native void ocvBitmapContrastSaturationSrc(Bitmap bitmapImg, Bitmap bitmapSrc, float contrast, float saturation);
    public static void ocvBitmapContrastSaturationSrcTimed(Bitmap bitmapImg, Bitmap bitmapSrc, float contrast, float saturation) {
        long t = System.nanoTime();
        ocvBitmapContrastSaturationSrc(bitmapImg, bitmapSrc, contrast, saturation);
        long dt = (System.nanoTime() - t) / 1000; // Microseconds
        Log.i("Native", "Applied contrast/saturation (from src) to bitmap in " + (dt / 1000.0f) + " ms");
    }

    public static native void ocvBitmapContrastSaturation(Bitmap bitmapImg, float contrast, float saturation);
    public static void ocvBitmapContrastSaturationTimed(Bitmap bitmapImg, float contrast, float saturation) {
        long t = System.nanoTime();
        ocvBitmapContrastSaturation(bitmapImg, contrast, saturation);
        long dt = (System.nanoTime() - t) / 1000; // Microseconds
        Log.i("Native", "Applied contrast/saturation to bitmap in " + (dt / 1000.0f) + " ms");
    }

}
```

Also `right click on project - >Android Tools -> Add Native Support`

```
Add Native Support is missing. I have Android Native Development Tools installed. Then also it's missing.
```

Comment: It looks like you have the wrong path for ndk-build configured in your ide.  Next verify with zip file tools that one or more .so files end up in .apk.  Finally are you explicitly loading the library from Java?

Comment: "D:\NDK\android-ndk-r9" this is my path of NDk and I set it in my ide. @ChrisStratton

Comment: As this project is done by another developer, so I am not sure what library you're talking about. But yes there are two folder in libs folder of the project one is "armeabi" and another is "armeabi-v7a". and every folder is containing two .so file. one is "libOAOAT.so" and another is "libopencv_java.so". Also there one library which is used "OpenCV Library - 2.4.3" is in same workspace. @ChrisStratton

Comment: You post an error message which suggests that nkd-build isn't at the slightly different path via which it was attempted to be run (or else there's some permission issue)  Also please check that the .so file is making it into the .apk file - that it is in the project folders is a start, but not the critical test.  Finally, you'll eventually need to verify the function name from the .so file itself - your tricky naming macro may or may not be working - I'd use the ndk objdump for that, but then I probably wouldn't bother with the macro in the first place.

Comment: I checked the apk file , it's containing the .so files. I want to know how to replace macro with what you suggested. Can you please provide me some link ? @ChrisStratton

Comment: See the hello-jni example from the ndk installation samples directory.

Comment: Or just see Usman's answer below for an example without the macro.

Comment: Okay let me check, if replacing Macro really works. @ChrisStratton

Comment: @ChrisStratton No it doesn't work. As I said, that code is completely working for what part the other dev done. But for my part the same library is not working.

Comment: That's an utterly meaningless comment, since different mechanisms are involved.  You are going to have to individually verify each link in the chain of components.

Comment: Voting to close this as "unclear what you are asking" because it has sat for 5 months without further clarification or feedback from the poster.

Comment: I really dont have any idea what to do further, Otherwise I would have posted an answer. ^^. Also we're not working on that project anymore.  So.. @ChrisStratton

Answer (score 1):

UnsatisfiedLinked error is due to broken bridge between java class and c class;
The name of the method in java should match to the method in C/c++ class.
While compiling bridge is created between Java and c/c++ so if method name is not correct it wont response.
example is following 
method name injava is following

```
public native String Stub(){}
```

that should be same in JNI but with your Application packagename+classname+methodname like following

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_packageName_ClassName_MethodName
```

Comment: I have added JNI file and SharedResources too. the function name is same
This is in SharedResources public static native void ocvBitmapPreMultAlpha(Bitmap bitmapImg, Bitmap bitmapMask);

and in JNI file it is same

Answer (score 0):

- Add the right NDK path in a new variable system: Ex. : "ANDROID_NDK=..."
- In the properties of you project, in "C/C++ Build", in the "Build command:" , enter this variable like this:  ${ANDROID_NDK}/ndk-build.cmd

Answer (score -1):

The key error is "Cannot run program "ndk-build": Launching failed". If that doesn't run, the .so does not get built, which results in the UnsatisfiedLinkError. Solve the ndk-build problem first.

Try removing the initial '\' from "\ndk-build.cmd". When I run "ndk-build.cmd", it works.

Comment: This was already covered extensively in comments.  The poster claims that the .so file is present in the apk - though perhaps not definitively so (in a current version), etc.  Essentially the question gives all appearances of having been abandoned last fall.

Comment: All I saw was people referring to Java code changes that they thought might be needed, and suggestions to fix the path to the NDK. Neither of those helped me. Removing the slash worked, and no one else suggested that.

Comment: That issue was suggested in the **first comment** posted five months ago.

Comment: You didn't specifically suggest he remove the leading slash. Your comment only referred to the path. He began to discuss "D:\NDK\android-ndk-r9" next, which demonstrated that he didn't take it to mean he should remove the slash. Your comment prompted me to check my path, which I found to be correct. The next thing I tried was to remove the leading slash. That fixed it. Why are you trying so hard to negate what I said? It worked.

Comment: I specifically told them it looked like they were trying to run it from the wrong path.  Since they then went on to say that there were .so files getting built, it seemed like this was not the primary issue in the question and had been incidentally overcome at some point.